# Firebase authenticating with wrong email or password displays strange error

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Whenever I auth against Firebase with the wrong password or email I get this error:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=<my-key> 400 ()
```

I'm using Angularfire2's login method with

```
{
  provider: AuthProviders.Password,
  method: AuthMethods.Password,
}
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to set up error handling. Something like this...

```js
login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
    },
    {
        provider: AuthProviders.Password,
        method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorMessage = error.message
        alert(errorMessage)
    })
}
```

You have to handle the response when the password is wrong. I'm not sure about the AngularFire way. I personally couldn't find it. I relied on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) to do this, which is linked in the AngularFire docs.